# Invalid Class/Method identifier, is this a bug?

Tags: apex, documentation, method

I was writing some unit tests just now, and was lazily creating more test methods when I ran across an error on trying to save my unit test.

```
> Compiling testOLIUpdateManualRollups.cls
> Compile Failed
> testOLIUpdateManualRollups.cls: Invalid identifier: testRollupNew_MRR_Total__c (Line: 364)
```

To make it very clear, I was attempting to create a new method called `testRollupNew_MRR_Total__c`

There's more to the test class that I'm writing, but the relevant Apex is simply

```
static testMethod void testRollupNew_MRR_Total__c(){
    // test as of yet to be written
}
```

Now, I know that [the keywords/reserved words](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm) can't be used alone as identifiers for classes, methods, or variables ('test_Integer_result' and the like are valid identifiers), but why isn't an identifier ending in `__c` valid for methods?

I can't find anything on this restriction in the [documentation for method declaration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm), and a cursory googling doesn't turn up anything either.

Upon further testing, it appears that `__c` cannot appear in any portion of the method name. Underscores at the start of an identifier also appear to be verboten, though this is legal in Java, and I can't find any documentation on that restriction either.

This strikes me as a either an oversight in the formal grammar for the Apex language or a bug in Salesforce's compiler (perhaps transpiler might be more accurate?). I can't see any situation where the compiler should expect a custom field identifier anywhere in a method declaration, so I'm at a bit of a loss here.

I'll be working around this by removing the `__c` from the method name. Just wondering if anybody else can confirm this or can offer an explanation.

Comment: It's not that surprising. I believe any identifier with `__` is illegal. I can't find a reference for it either, however.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that a double underscore could be part of a valid identifier. Just tested that, and it appears to be invalid.

Comment: I suppose perhaps this could have something to do with being restricted due to the syntax used to declare a trigger. It just popped into my mind that this is the only place I've seen `__c` as part of a legal identifier.

Comment: It probably tries to figure out if it's a namespace or custom field and gets confused.

Comment: @AdrianLarson That would indicate a bug in Salesforce's parser or syntax analyzer, or perhaps even the grammar for the Apex lexer. I can see why `__c` may be problematic at the end of a method identifier. If the lexer adheres to the maximal munch principle though, there's no excuse for making `__` illegal (well, at least not in the lexer).

Comment: Except if it were trying to consider everything before it the namespace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35527/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-derek-f).

Comment: Although I couldn't find any official documentation from SF to support the consecutive use of underscores `__` is illegal, but I found this. Try to create a custom field/permission set (or any metadata actually) with that illegal sequence, you will see the error message. It's because of the rule that SF set with the API name.

Comment: i'll bet if you go through the trouble of reporting this as a bug, it will come back as WAD - working as designed

Comment: @DerekF I see that it is documented for the class name but not for the method. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_classes.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two consecutive underscore characters in Apex are used to separate namespace of a managed package from the inner name inside of a managed package.

This is the reason why they are forbidden in Apex Class names, methods, variables and properties.